# How to distribute items in a random positions in a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I want to create a layout that contains items in an unorganized positions not vertically or horizontally, i tried to use `GridLayout` but can\t distribute the items as i want, this is the layout i want to build:

[image]

so, how can I build something like that?

Comment: just extend a ViewGroup

Comment: use RelativeLayout,
the real art will be how you will relate items with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested LinearLayouts and RelativeLayouts. The image with four buttons in the top right looks like Vertical layout to me.